# Почему в Stack изображение видно под Cantainer? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

Стоит задача сделать виджет в котором на изображение накладывается текс с его названием.
Я создал стэк, положил в него изображение, растянул его с помощью BoxFit.cover и сверху наложил контейнер с текстом. Из под контейнера виднеется часть изображения. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Container(
  width: width,
  height: height,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
      border: Border.all(width: 1, color: AppColors.neutrals_200)),
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: [
        Image.file(File(filePath), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: height * 0.6,
              width: width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  color: AppColors.white),
              child: Text(
                fileName,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyles.paragraphSMSemiBold(
                    textColors: AppColors.neutrals_900),
              ),
            ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать сontainer color transparent, так как он находится выше чем изображение и из-за этого цвет Container перекрывает.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]